# connect android application to pc

Tags: java, android, outlook

i want to crate application that sync my android phone to outlook on windows

i can fetch data in application running in pc but i need it in phone

which is better way?

1. create client that run on pc and behave ad bridge between phone and pc? if tes then please explain how , is socjey connection possible?
2. i am usin [moyasoft api](http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/) for pc, so is that direcly possible through android phone?

i want to connect through cable

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple client application on PC that uses Internet connection and using that internet connection post the PC data on server if it is mostly of text form and then u can retrieve your data in phone by calling a web service created by you.

I have done the same thing in Windows Phone but for text only data like emails , sms contacts etc.

hope this helps up to some extent.

Comment: i already thought that but i dont want to create any web service, cant i connect using any stream like socket connection